# Not able to get the updated data in LWC Lightning data table

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have lightning datatable with inline edit . With draftvalues i am able to get the edited values and using updated record I am able to update.
It reflected in the backend and not in ui.

LWC JS

```
@track datanew;
saveDraftValues = [];


handleSave(event) {
        this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        const recordInputs = this.saveDraftValues.slice().map(draft => {
            const fields = Object.assign({}, draft);
            console.log('fields======'+fields+'=='+JSON.stringify(fields));
            return { fields };
        });
        console.log('draft======'+JSON.stringify(this.saveDraftValues));
        console.log('rec======'+this.recordInputs);
        // Updateing the records using the UiRecordAPi
        const promises = recordInputs.map(recordInput => updateRecord(recordInput));
        Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Records Updated Successfully!!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
                
            );
            
            this.saveDraftValues = [];
            console.log('=datanew====='+JSON.stringify(this.datanew));
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    message: 'An Error Occured!!',
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(() => {
            this.saveDraftValues = [];
        });
    }


EX:
```

draft======`

```
[{"City__c":"test","Id":"0017F000036b5AoQAI"},{"City__c":"test1","Id":"0017F000036b5ApQAI"}]`
```

=datanew=====

```
[{"Id":"0017F000036b5AoQAI","Name":"wer","City__c":"car","Description":"test","url":"/0017F000036b5AoQAI"},
{"Id":"0017F000036b5ApQAI","Name":"teddy","City__c":"bike","Description":"radha","url":"/0017F000036b5ApQAI"},
{"Id":"0017F000036b5AoQPI","Name":"squid","City__c":"ind","Description":"test","url":"/0017F000036b5AoQPI"}]
```

Datanew should be updated with draft values
Please help me

Comment: You never update datanew, so it would still have the old values. You have to update the data somehow. This might be by way of applying the draftValues to datanew, or by calling a wire service or imperative Apex, etc.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please help me with applying the draftvalues to datanew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where `datanew` comes from. If it comes from Apex, you need to call the appropriate method to refresh the data.

```
// datanew is loaded via wire method
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex'
```

...

```
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
  refreshApex(this.datanew);
```

Or:

```
// datanew is loaded via imperative apex call
Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
  getTableData({}).then(data => {
    this.datanew = data;
  });
```

Otherwise, you can just apply the values directly:

```
this.datanew.forEach(data => 
  Object.assign(
    data, 
    event.detail.draftValues.find(draft => draft.Id === data.Id)
  )
)
```